# How to put text next to an image, so it is centered on the page and responsive as well? Thanks

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to put the text right and image left next to it, so that I have some space on the left and right margin as well(equal). I got stuck with pixels and widths, so when I shrink the window it is not responsive and does not wrap nicely. I add 100% width in the media query as well, but even then it still has spaces and sliders when the window is shrinked. Would appreciate help...

```
<article>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg">
</article>

<aside>
<h3>Text text</h3><br>
<p>
text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttextexttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttextxt texttext texttext texttext text
text text text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text
</p>
</aside>
```

here is my css

```
article img{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -27px;
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 4%;
}

aside {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of floating the `aside`, use a `margin-left: 47%;`:

```css
article img{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-top: -27px;
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 4%;
}

aside {
    margin-left: 47%;
    width: 45%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg">
</article>

<aside>
<h3>Text text</h3><br>
<p>
text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttextexttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttextxt texttext texttext texttext text
text text text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text
</p>
</aside>
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6vaogzr/)